# Xslt stylesheet to get the id and number value from the provided XML

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, saxon-js

I have been provided a Soap XML file which contains multiple records from where I need to fetch the data of Id,CaseNumber etc. Also this records has multiple "records" tag within "sf:Case_Responses_GCC_r" tag. I need to create an XSLT file which could help me in transforming this SOAP XML into the plain XML with those values.

**The SOAP XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns="urn:enter.soap.force.com"
  xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enter.soap.force.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <queryMoreResponse>
      <result>
        <done>false</done>
        <records xsi:type="sf:Case">
          <sf:Id>6896SDRGrt868</sf:Id>
          <sf:PolicyNumber>445353566</sf:PolicyNumber>
           <sf:Case_Responses_GCC__r>
             <records xsi:type="sf:Response_GCC__c">
               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
               <sf:Question_GCC__c>Available to question?</sf:Question_GCC__c>
               <sf:Response_GCC__c>Yes</sf:Response_GCC__c>
             </records>
             <records xsi:type="sf:Response_GCC__c">
              <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
              <sf:Question_GCC__c>Relationship</sf:Question_GCC__c>
              <sf:Response_GCC__c>Self</sf:Response_GCC__c>
             </records>
           </sf:Case_Responses_GCC__r>
        </records>
        <records xsi:type="sf:Case">
          <sf:Id>5003L005UCcfVVS</sf:Id>
          <sf:PolicyNumber>87768978</sf:PolicyNumber>
           <sf:Case_Responses_GCC__r>
             <records xsi:type="sf:Response_GCC__c">
               <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
               <sf:Question_GCC__c>Available to question?</sf:Question_GCC__c>
               <sf:Response_GCC__c>No</sf:Response_GCC__c>
             </records>
             <records xsi:type="sf:Response_GCC__c">
              <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
              <sf:Question_GCC__c>Relationship</sf:Question_GCC__c>
              <sf:Response_GCC__c>Father</sf:Response_GCC__c>
             </records>
           </sf:Case_Responses_GCC__r>
        </records>
      </result>
    </queryMoreResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="urn:enter.soap.force.com"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:urn="urn:enter.soap.force.com"
  xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enter.soap.force.com"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi sf urn">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <report>
           <reportid>
             <xsl:value-of select="//records/sf:Id"/>
           </reportid>
           <policynumber>
             <xsl:value-of select="//records/sf:PolicyNumber"/>
           </policynumber>
        </report>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As, I don't have much understanding of this XSLT format data, still I was able to extract something, but still that does not make sense as it does not have the tag with them just plain.

I need an output in XML like this each record in an array , as I will be looping over them and converting it to JSON format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lic lang="en">
   <report>
      <reportversion>1</reportversion>
      <reportid>6896SDRGrt868</reportid>
      <policynum>445353566</policynum>
      <primarysourcecountry>IN</primarysourcecountry>
      <client>
         <summary>
                Available to question?: Yes
                Relationship: Self
         </summary>
      </client>
   </report>
   <report>
      <reportversion>1</reportversion>
      <reportid>5003L005UCcfVVS</reportid>
      <policynum>87768978</policynum>
      <primarysourcecountry>IN</primarysourcecountry>
      <client>
         <summary>
           Available to question?: No
           Relationship: Father     
         </summary>
      </client>
   </report>
</lic>
```

Comment: Please show the **exact** result you expect to get from the given example input, and explain the required logic in words.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Have updated the result that I need

Comment: " need an output in XML like this each record in an array , as I will be looping over them and converting it to JSON format.": are you aware that XSLT 3 supports serializing to JSON directly with `xsl:output method="json"` for XDM/XPath/XSLT maps/arrays? Do you really need both the XML you have shown (as an intermediary format) and then some JSON or isn't it perhaps easier to have the XSLT directly serialize to JSON?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I was not knowing that, then having json directly would be really great.

Comment: Given that the question is answered now if you want help with a direct JSON serialization in XSLT 3 consider to ask a new question where you show the exact JSON you want to produce.

Comment: @MartinHonnen As Michael has provided the solution, I think I can try using it to get Json by changing the output tag method to json. If that does not works will ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: changing the output tag method to json will NOT work. It will still produce some kind of xml

Comment: @MartinHonnen Created a new question to get JSON serialization in XSLT 3  [Link To New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76868091/xslt-stylesheet-to-get-json-output-from-xml-using-xslt-3-0-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enter.soap.force.com"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:enter.soap.force.com"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/soapenv:Envelope">
    <lic lang="en">
        <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Body/queryMoreResponse/result/records">
            <report>
                <reportversion>1</reportversion>
                <reportid>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sf:Id"/>
                </reportid>
                <policynum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sf:PolicyNumber"/>
                </policynum>
                <primarysourcecountry>IN</primarysourcecountry>
                <client>
                    <summary>
                        <xsl:for-each select="sf:Case_Responses_GCC__r/records">
                            <xsl:value-of select="sf:Question_GCC__c"/>
                            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sf:Response_GCC__c"/>
                            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </summary>
                </client>
            </report>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </lic>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
$nsSf = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('sf')

$xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><lic lang="en"></lic>'
$doc1 = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xmlText)
$lic = $doc1.Root

$result = $doc.Descendants($ns + "result")[0]
$records = $result.Elements($ns + "records")

foreach($record in $records)
{
   $report = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('report'))
   $lic.Add($report)

   $reportVersion = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('reportversion'),1)
   $report.Add($reportVersion)

   $id = $record.Element($nsSf + 'Id').Value
   $reportId = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('reportid'),$id)
   $report.Add($xId)

   $policyNumber = $record.Element($nsSf + 'PolicyNumber').Value
   $xPolicynum = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('policynum'),$policyNumber)
   $report.Add($xPolicynum)

   $xPrimarysourcecountry = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('primarysourcecountry'),'IN')
   $report.Add($xprimarysourcecountry)

   $client = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('client'))
   $report.Add($client)

   $summary = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.Xname]::get('summary'))
   $client.Add($summary)

   $writer = [System.IO.StringWriter]::new()
   $writer.WriteLine()
   $responses = $record.Descendants($ns + 'records')
   foreach($response in $responses)
   {
      $question = $response.Element($nsSf + 'Question_GCC__c').Value
      $answer = $response.Element($nsSf + 'Response_GCC__c').Value
      $writer.WriteLine($question + ': ' + $answer)
   }
   $innertext = $writer.ToString()
   $summary.AddFirst([string]$innertext)
}

$doc1.Save($outputFilename)
```